# how to pass array in PdfMake to make table

Tags: angular, pdf, multidimensional-array, pdf-generation, pdfmake

console.log(this.pgCheckOutList);
[image: pgCheckOutList]

i need this data for table in PdfMake
[image: like this]

plz someone help me

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass it to content like this:

```
{
      table: {
        headerRows: 1,
        widths: '*',
        body: [
                ['col1','col2','col3'],//header
                ['col1value','col3value','col3value']//values
                ['col1value','col3value','col3value']//values
              ]
      },
      layout: this.layout()
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array and add the column values to that array and pass that in the content

For e.g.

```
const exs = [];
this.mathsQuestions.forEach(exp=>{

  exs.push([
    {
      columns:[
        [

          {
            text: 'QuestionNo ' 
          },
          {
            text:  exp.questionHeader 
          }
        ]
      ]
    }

  ]);

});
 var test = 
        {

          content: [
            {
              text: this.selectedQuestionType,
              bold: true,
              fontSize: 20,
              alignment: 'center',
              margin: [0, 0, 0, 20]
            },
            exs    

            ]};

pdfMake.createPdf(content).open();
```